# Visual Studio Code-editor Indicator Margin Glyph Reference

Tags: visual-studio-2013, editor, visual-studio-2015

Along the left side of the Visual Studio editor is a grey margin called the "Indicator Margin." This is where Bookmarks and the red dot for a break point are displayed for example.  I'm looking for a reference page showing all of the standard glyphs with an explanation of what they indicate. I've searched the net, and can't find one. I did find this one for VS6:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa238792(v=VS.60).aspx

It's a good example what I'd like to find for VS 2013 or 15.

I've also thought about seeing if I could extract the glyphs from vs somehow as well by creating an extension. If I go this route what object would have the standard glyphs, and can I access it from my extension? I can see where I can add a glyph, but not sure if I can extract all of the existing ones.

So my Question is: Do you know of an online reference sheet to the standard glyphs? and, would it be possible to use C#, or VB to extract the glyphs from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

There's an online reference for both the StandardGlyphGroup and the KnownMonikers here: http://glyphlist.azurewebsites.net/standardglyphgroup/

Comment: Thanks Omer!  If i could set this as the answer, I would.

Comment: @fossfool why can't you?

Answer (score 0):

Just to document my findings here: According to Microsoft, a public reference sheet doesn't exist. They offered the link below about the debugging glyphs:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/008h021s(v=vs.100).aspx