# Is there a Visual Studio 2019 master icon key that explain icons next to line numbers (Indicator Margin)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

What do all of these symbols mean (like "<" or "'" at the top, etc.) in VS19 C++ Indicator Margin.

E.g. in my code:    `char fooBar[FOO]; // FOO is a constexpr auto FOO = 10` has a `[ ]` to the left.

[image]

I know how to turn them off in Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Indicator Margin. No link to more info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-general?view=vs-2022#indicator-margin.

I've tried SO, the MS VS Help pages, and Googling but reached my limit and can only find *individual/specific* answers (like what is the green bar, or what is the light bulb) but nothing that points to some *master* table of icon meanings?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/margin-indicators is only a short-list.

Comment: do you have any extensions?

Comment: A complete list is [not that practical](http://glyphlist.azurewebsites.net/knownmonikers/)

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, VS IntelliCode, VS Rich Navigation, and VsVim. I turned the first two off and nothing. I tried Disabling VsVim and my code windows won't display (all white), so it's possible it is this Extension I suppose if these indicators aren't VS native..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For VS guidance (built-ins): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/margin-indicators
2. For 3rd party master icon/glyph: http://glyphlist.azurewebsites.net/knownmonikers/ thanks @hans-passant
3. For the specific Extension VsVim that prints these special characters in my personal case, like `[]` `<` `,`: https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim/blob/master/Src/VimCore/CoreTypes.fs#L487 thanks for the idea @daniel-a-white

Related SO:

- [What does the various brackets mean on the indicator margin of Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66997403/what-does-the-various-brackets-mean-on-the-indicator-margin-of-visual-studio-201/74878216#74878216)
- [Visual Studio Code Editor Indicator Margin Glyph Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865906/visual-studio-code-editor-indicator-margin-glyph-reference)

Comment: That first link looks like it's documentation for the margin indicators in the Office VBA editor, not Visual Studio.